# How to resolve hostname of AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, hostname

I try to access a service in an AWS EC2 I installed. It showed error:

> do not know what is ip-10-124-123-122

How to resolve the private hostname of the EC2: `ip-10-124-123-122`?

This two links show I can change hostname of the `ip-10-124-123-122` to the domain name of the EC2:

1. set `enableDnsHostnames` and `enableDnsSupport` to true in VPC:
   [Using DNS with Your VPC - Amazon Virtual Private Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html)
2. change hostname from `ip-10-124-123-122` to `domainname`:
   [Changing the Hostname of Your Linux Instance - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html)

Note I do have a domain name for the webserver of EC2:port 80 but it is nothing to do with the hostname of the EC2. Because I created the domain name using this way:

```
https://domainname->route53->ALB:443->targetgroup->EC2 port 80.
```

Note: the EC2 is in a non-default VPC and the VPC already has DNS resolution and DNS hostnames enabled.

If I type `nslookup ip-10-X-X-X.region.compute.internal` at an EC2 in the same subnet of that EC2, I can see the IP but the IP of that EC2 is not resolved.

If I type `nslookup ip-10-X-X-X.region.compute.internal` in my machine where I try to access the service;

Note: if I `nslookup ip-10-124-123-122` won't get EC2 resolved. maybe this is the reason?

Are the above steps enough to resolve the hostname of the EC2? if not. how to resolve the error: do not know what is `ip-10-124-123-122`?

Comment: You need to use the **Full DNS Name**, not just the first part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each Amazon EC2 instance has a **Public DNS Name** and a **Private DNS Name**.

The Public DNS Name will look something like this:

```
ec2-54-252-207-11.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

This can be resolved on the Internet. It will actually be resolved to `54.252.207.11` as suggested by the name.

The Private DNS Name will look something like this:

```
ip-172-31-10-201.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
```

It will be resolved to `172.31.10.201`.

The private DNS Name can only be resolved **within the VPC where it exists**. This is because the IP address only makes sense within that private network.

From a computer on the Internet, I can resolve the public address:

```
$ nslookup ec2-54-252-207-77.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Server:     192.168.1.1
Address:    192.168.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ec2-54-252-207-77.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
Address: 54.252.207.77
```

From an Amazon EC2 instance within the same VPC, I can resolve the internal IP address:

```
$ nslookup ip-172-31-10-201.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Server:     172.31.0.2
Address:    172.31.0.2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   ip-172-31-10-201.ap-southeast-2.compute.internal
Address: 172.31.10.201
```

**Bottom line:** It appears you are not using the **full DNS Name**, which is why it is not working for you. This is like trying to resolve `facebook` instead of `facebook.com`. It will not work. (Well, it will if you define a default network search domain, but that's not really suitable here.)

Comment: I use https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=320576 to route from route53 to ip and I added a domain in /etc/resolv.conf and now ip-10-124-123-122 can be resolve to it's ip 10.124.123.122